# How do I exclude all images from a wp_query?

Tags: wp-query, images, attachments

I want to query attachments and exclude all images.

I can see how to include *only* images, using `'post_mime_type' => 'image/*'`, but I couldn't find any way of achieving the opposite. Is there any mime_type equivalent of `posts__not_in`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Pretty much the solution is to include all mimes *except* images. WordPress has a nifty little function where it keeps all it's accepted mime-types called [`get_allowed_mime_types()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_allowed_mime_types) ( cleverly named ) which returns an Array() of mimes. All we need to do is get the difference between the returned array and the array of mime-types we don't want in our query:

```
$unsupported_mimes  = array( 'image/jpeg', 'image/gif', 'image/png', 'image/bmp', 'image/tiff', 'image/x-icon' );
$all_mimes          = get_allowed_mime_types();
$accepted_mimes     = array_diff( $all_mimes, $unsupported_mimes );
$attachment_query   = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'         => 'attachment',
    'post_status'       => 'inherit',
    'post_mime_type'    => $accepted_mimes,
    'posts_per_page'    => 20,
) );
```

Comment: Simple, I like it!

Comment: Nice - I'd reached a similar conclusion but was doing it via $wpdb. This is much neater.

Comment: I've come across a follow up issue - any ideas? Thanks. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/209802/ignore-a-filter-on-the-media-library

Answer (score 4):

If you also want to include post types other than attachments (e.g. posts, pages) that don't have any mime type, you'll have to use the `posts_where` filter:

```
add_filter( 'posts_where' , 'remove_images' );

function remove_images($where) {
    global $wpdb;
    $where.=' AND '.$wpdb->posts.'.post_mime_type NOT LIKE \'image/%\'';
    return $where;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty much certain there isn't an equivalent of `posts_not_in` for mime types.

You could of course query for all attachments that are images. Preferably just returning the IDs via parameter `fields` set to `ids`. Then you can use those IDs with `posts__not_in` on a second query. Drawback being that you need two queries.

Another possibility would be to hook into the `posts_where` filter and apply some SQL to get your result like you want it.

Comment: +1 - I actually had to use the `posts_where` filter as per your question in the end because of other details I'd left out of my question, but am keeping the other answer as accepted as it answers the question I posed.

Comment: Sure, no problem. The main thing is you solved it. @BFDatabaseAdmin

Comment: I've come across a follow up issue - any ideas? Thanks. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/209802/ignore-a-filter-on-the-media-library