# Ignore a filter on the media library

Tags: wp-query, filters, uploads, media, media-library

As per my [question yesterday](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/209712/how-do-i-exclude-all-images-from-a-wp-query), I need to exclude all images from *most* of my WordPress queries - yesterday, I thought I needed to exclude them from all queries, until I came upon the following issue.

Excluding images using the following filter also excludes them from the media library, including the insert media dialog.

```
function remove_images($where) {
    global $wpdb;
    $where.=' AND '.$wpdb->posts.'.post_mime_type NOT LIKE \'image/%\'';
    return $where;
}
```

I still want to be able to see images in my media library and insert media dialog.

Normally, I could just put in an `if (!is_admin())` clause, because media library is usually seen in the admin section.

**However**, I also have a `wp_editor` in the front end to allow my users to quickly add posts - and you can also access the media library from there.

Is there any hook or condition that I can use so that the filter isn't included when querying the media library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`is_admin()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin) in conjunction with the admin global variable [`$pagenow`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables#Admin_Globals) to make sure you're not on either the upload or media page:

```
function remove_images( $where ) {
    global $wpdb,
        $pagenow;

    if( is_admin() && in_array( $pagenow, array( 'upload.php', 'media-upload.php' ) ) {
        return $where
    }

    $where  .=  " AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_mime_type NOT LIKE 'image/%'";
    return $where;
}
```