# WP Query search for attachments and their exact title

Tags: wp-query, images, search

Due to lack of reputation, I must now ask the question. I want to create a search for all images in the media libary. The search result should only appear if you search for the exact title of the image.
I already tried it with **'exact' => true** but it does not work. Still get similar images displayed. 
I have created a query with the following parameters:

```
<?php
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_mime_type' => 'image',
        'orderby' => 'post_date',
        'order' => 'desc',
        'posts_per_page' => '30',
        'post_status'    => 'inherit',
         );

     $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_the_ID() );
echo "<img src='" . $image[0] . "'>";

endwhile; ?>
```

Hope that somebody can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that

The reverse of this: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/209714/180599

```
<?php
global $wpdb;

//The reverse of this: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/209714/180599
$supported_mimes = array( 'image/jpeg', 'image/gif', 'image/png', 'image/bmp', 'image/tiff', 'image/x-icon' );
$all_mimes = get_allowed_mime_types();
$accepted_mimes = array_diff($supported_mimes, $all_mimes);

//and...
$keyword = stripslashes($_REQUEST['keyword']);
//$search = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( " SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_title = '%s' OR post_content = '%s' ", $keyword, $keyword ) );
$search = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( " SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_title = '%s' ", $keyword ) );
$query = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment', 
    'post_status' => 'inherit',
    'orderby' => 'date', 
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'post_mime_type' => $accepted_mimes,
    'post__in' => $search,
);  
$attachments = new WP_Query($query);
while($attachments->have_posts()):
    $attachments->the_post();

    echo $attachment->post_content.'<br>';
    echo $attachment->post_title.'<br>';
    //echo wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment->ID, 'medium', true )[0].'<hr>';
    echo wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID).'<hr>';

endwhile;
?>
```